# Cómo ubicar un botón flotante react en el centro de un borde de la pantalla

Tags: reactjs

Lo que quisiera saber es cómo centrarlo en el borde derecho (cerca del borde derecho y centrado respecto al los border inferior y superior) o en el borde inferior (cerca del borde inferior y centrado respecto a derecha e izquierda.

Sé colocar un botón cerca de cualquiera de las esquina cambiando bottom por top y right por left:

```js
const useStylesScrollTop = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
    createStyles({
        root: {
            position: 'fixed',
            bottom: theme.spacing(2),
            right: theme.spacing(2),
        },
    }),
);
```

Por ejemplo con algo como https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497631/how-to-add-floating-action-button-on-the-right-bottom-side-of-the-screen-using-m podría ponerlo en la esquina donde está el circulo celeste.

Quiero saber cómo ponerlo en la posición 1 o 2.

[image: imagen con botón abajo centrado]

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar un ejemplo (imagen) de lo que quieres obtener? Yo no lo entiendo en tu descripción.

Comment: @V0LT3RR4 agregué una imágen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo, para el punto marcado en la imagen como **1** puedes usar el siguiente estilo:

```
<button style={{position: 'fixed', bottom: 0, right: '50%'}}>Centro borde inferior</button>
```

Para el caso **2** puedes usar:

```
<button style={{position: 'fixed', top: '50%', right: 0}}>Centro borde derecho</button>
```

[Aquí una muestra en CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-taussig-16u50?file=/src/App.js).

Para tener mayor precisión en caso de un elemento grande, donde se pueda notar el desfase con el centro, debes tener en cuenta ese desfase de acuerdo al tamaño del elemento. Es decir, tendrías que darle un tamaño predeterminado al botón o elemento para poder acomodar y centrar perfectamente.

Comment: Es una muy buena aproximación. Gracias